# httplib.ResponseNotReady with api.ai

Tags: python-2.7, httplib, dialogflow-es

I am trying to make my own chatbot with api.ai.

The first time it goes good but then the second time I get this error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/Documents/Projects/Darlene/core/api.py", line 34, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/Documents/Projects/Darlene/core/api.py", line 28, in main
    speech, action = b.handle(cmd)
  File "/root/Documents/Projects/Darlene/core/api.py", line 15, in handle
    response = self.request.getresponse().read()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/apiai/requests/request.py", line 133, in getresponse
    return self._connection.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/httplib.py", line 1123, in getresponse
    raise ResponseNotReady()
httplib.ResponseNotReady
```

It looks like there is a problem with the api or so. But I am not sure. 
Here is my code:

```
import apiai
import json



class Bot(object):
    def __init__(self, client_token='<clientToken>'):

        self.AI = apiai.ApiAI(client_token)
        self.request = self.AI.text_request()
        self.request.lang = 'en'

    def handle(self, text):
        self.request.query = text
        response = self.request.getresponse().read()
        speech = str(json.loads(response)['result']['fulfillment']['speech'])
        action = str(json.loads(response)['result']['action'])
        if action is not '':
            return speech, action
        else:
            return speech, None


def main():
    b = Bot()
    while True:
        cmd = raw_input('me; ')
        speech, action = b.handle(cmd)
        print speech
        if action is not None:
            print 'action'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Does anyone know a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Please, don't reuse a request. Just for each stage create new request. Likewise this:

```
def handle(self, text):
    self.request = self.AI.text_request()
    self.request.lang = 'en'

    self.request.query = text
    response = self.request.getresponse().read()
    speech = str(json.loads(response)['result']['fulfillment']['speech'])
    action = str(json.loads(response)['result']['action'])
    if action is not '':
        return speech, action
    else:
        return speech, None
```

Comment: Why shouldn't I reuse a request?

Answer (score 0):

#### after the read() use decode('utf-8').

And since you're at the beginning it would be a good idea now to move your code to Python 3.5 instead of 2.7...

apiai_request.getresponse().read().decode('utf-8'))

Notice that it's unfortunate that they named in their example "request" since it conflicts with the requests library, flask request etc... but that's life.